# VS2022 The operation failed as details for project could not be loaded

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget-package-restore, visual-studio-2022

This error occurred unexpectedly when I worked on my Blazor project as usual yesterday. When I tried to clean, build, rebuild the project, the process hung with this message, and all dependencies in the project(Analyzers, Frameworks, Packages) has an exclamation mark.
Then I tried to use the Package Manager Console. The `Install-Package` command also results in the same error.
I searched the whole Internet looking for a solution, here's what I've tried:

- Disable ReSharper 2022
- Delete VS caches(the .vs folder in the root directory of the project) and build results(the bin and obj folders)
- Clear NuGet caches
- Unload and reload the project
- Reopen VS2022
- Move project to a new location(with no special character in the path)
- Open other projects
- Create new projects
- Restart computer
- Update VS2022 to the latest version
- Reinstall VS2022
- Use VS2022 Preview
- Uninstall VS2022 and return to an older version

None of these efforts worked.
To be mentioned, the `dotnet restore` and `dotnet build` command still works, and the VS2019 on my computer also works fine(but the current project is based on .Net 6, so I have to use VS2022).
To provide more information, here the result of `dotnet --info` of my current VS2022(17.0.3):

```
.NET SDK (global.json):
 Version:   6.0.101
 Commit:    ef49f6213a

Runtime environments:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.19042
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.101\

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 6.0.1
  Commit:  3a25a7f1cc

.NET SDKs installed:
  2.1.700 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.801 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  3.0.103 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  5.0.405 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  6.0.101 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.11 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.12 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.28 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.30 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.11 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.12 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.28 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.30 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.0.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.22 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.14 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.1 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.11 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.12 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.28 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.30 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.0.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.22 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.14 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.1 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.0.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.22 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.14 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.1 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
```

I've been struggling with this problem for the whole night, driving me crazy.
Any suggestions or solutions will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 9):

in your project file comment out ProjectTypeGuids
save and restart VS - it will reload then - not sure why it happens though.

Comment: I had this problem for one project in a solution after upgrading to VS2022 and this solution worked. Great find! Probably saved me an hour of more Google searching.

Comment: I was not able to load an old vb.net asp.net web application and this solution works perfectly! Thanks

Comment: Though I marked this answer as useful, you just have to be careful. My web project got converted to a console library. I readded the ProjectTypeGuids when my project loaded.

Comment: This solved my issue, I was able to load the project. However, the project was loaded as a regular class library instead of an asp.net web project, so I uncommented the ProjectTypeGuids and restarted VS again. This time everything was working as intended.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced this problem. After uninstalling antivirus and clearing nuget cache, it's resolved.

Comment: Thanks for your solution! Before uninstalling antivirus, have you tried reinstalling VS2022?

Comment: no，just uninstall antivirus ,then clear nuget cache

Comment: Unbelievable, it's really solved after uninstalling 360 safe! How rediculous!

Answer (score 0):

I had an old solution/repo, and installed it on a new computer that had not had previous versions of VS installed on it.  Two projects in the solution failed to load.

After a whole lot of back and forth, I reduced the required changes to get it to work for one project down to:

```
-  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="false" />
+  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v17.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" />
```